# My video player in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS lags

Tags: gnome, 18.04, video-player, animations

The frame rate appears to lag a lot but the sound works fine.
Also, I feel that the animation on my desktop is lagging a bit too. Videos on firefox and chrome work fine.
I have upgraded from 16.10 LTS.

I have hp pavilion with i5 processor

Comment: which video player are you using?

Comment: I personally use mpv. It is amazing. No lag at all. I will suggest you to give it a try.

Comment: Using MPV with SMPlayer frontend for over a uear now. Lighter and very good quality playback. However if animation lags throughout the whole system you probably should try a lighter Ubuntu flavours. My personal favourite is Xubuntu :-)

Comment: I am using the default Totem Movie Player application.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone who suggested mpv.  Works like a charm.

Comment: I reported it for cheese developers, but I commented that it affects many other packages. You can subscribe here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1777238

Answer (score 2):

Is the monitor refresh rate.
   With me it happened in any video that was in the browser or Totem VLC etc.
    Under Settings go to> Devices> Monitors> Resolution. click to change. At this point there is the resolution chosen by the system and just below the same resolution. choose the second option and the Update Rate will appear. Choose the one from your monitor if not already ... 60Hz, 120Hz etc. Do the test.

Comment: After decreasing the frequency, VLC worked for me...

Comment: this didn't fix my problem. I am sure it comes from somewhere else. It affects many softwares: Cheese, Super Tux Cart, VLC (when you rewind in the film), youtube, Hangouts and every software where video is played.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. its same to me. 
please use vlc media player.
open software center (Ubuntu Software) and find vlc and just[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWsQZ.png) install it

Comment: Vlc is creating some problems too. I switched to mpv and it works good.

Comment: @Ubix_noob_94 I love **mpv** and there are tons of CLI options for using mpv, some guy can say that it is very simple and  it's good for begginer but I don't  think that it's good for begginer due to the tons of CLI options (and beginners don't use CLI).

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT!

Go into **BIOS** disable all Intel speed/power saving modes. C States, EIST, SpeedStep, etc. Adjust for simply Low Power or High Performance without all of the further features that try to overclock during low usage or to adjust voltages.